# Can't serialize Ajax form

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make a drop down menu that whenever an option is selected it needs to update a row in a database. I'm creating the drop down menu with this code

Form

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("PartialViewName", "admin", null, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "Post",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            //LoadingElementId = "LoadingLink",
            UpdateTargetId = "PartialViewName"

        }, new { id = "connectNewForm" }))
```

The drop down code

```
<select name="statusDD" onchange="ChangeStatus(this.value)">
            <option value="">Update Status</option>
            <option value="1">Open</option>
            <option value="2 ">In Progress</option>
            <option value="3">Pending</option>
            <option value="4">To Be Verified</option>
            <option value="5">Approved</option>
            <option value="6">Disapproved</option>
            <option value="7">Closed</option>
        </select>
```

The ChangeStatus

```
function ChangeStatus() {

    var form = jQuery(".FormID");

    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/ActionResult",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        error: function (e) {

            if (form == null) {
                alert("DIDN'T WORK FORM IS NULL");
            }
            else {
                alert("DIDN'T WORK something else");
            }


        },
        success: function (response) {
            // A response to say if it's updated or not
            alert("worked");
        }
    });

}
```

In the controller

```
public ActionResult UpdateStatus(int id, FormCollection formValues)
  {

    int ID = util.IntUtilParse(formValues["ID"]);
    int newStatus = util.IntUtilParse(formValues["Status"]);
    using (var dbContext = new Project.OpenAccess.DataBase())
    {
        //var swm = dbContext.StoredProcedure(
        var swm = dbContext.StoredProcedure(ID, newStatus);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Whenever I select an option it goes through the ajax and then throws an error and never makes it to the controller. I'm very new to Ajax and I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: You need to use '#FormId' if you are really want to jQuery to select the form using its Id. `var form = jQuery("#FormID");`. Also look in the browser console and post the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/ActionResult",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
```

Try changing to

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost\\:#####/{Controller Name}/UpdateStatus',
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
```

Not 100% on your application logic, but this is why you're not hitting the controller. Note that the placeholder is indicating the name of your controller, since the name of it is not posted. For example if the name is `CustomerController` then your ajax url will look as such `url: 'http://localhost\\:#####/Customer/UpdateStatus'`

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't it. Its to update a form in a database. Since the status in a separate table from the actual form I need to grab the form's ID to update the status.

Comment: Are you hitting the controller at least? It might help to decorate your controller action method with the appropriate get/post annotation

Comment: I'm not hitting the controller at all and I've tried using the annotation.

Comment: add `type: "POST"` to your ajax definition. I have a feeling it'll still yell at you because of the controller parameters. Can you provide the error you get from the web console?

Comment: Adding type: "POST" was it. Thank you very much.

Comment: np, I'll edit the answer so others may find it useful. Happy coding